# Http Auth in a Firefox 3 bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, firefox, delicious-api

I'm trying to create a bookmarklet for posting del.icio.us bookmarks to a separate account.

I tested it from the command line like:

```
wget -O - --no-check-certificate \
"https://seconduser:thepassword@api.del.icio.us/v1/posts/add?url=http://seet.dk&description=test"
```

This works great.

I then wanted to create a bookmarklet in my firefox. I googled and found bits and pieces and ended up with:

```
javascript:void(
    open('https://seconduser:password@api.del.icio.us/v1/posts/add?url='
          +encodeURIComponent(location.href)
          +'&description='+encodeURIComponent(document.title),
          'delicious','toolbar=no,width=500,height=250'
        )
    );
```

But all that happens is that I get this from del.icio.us:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<result code="access denied" />
<!-- fe04.api.del.ac4.yahoo.net uncompressed/chunked Thu Aug  7 02:02:54 PDT 2008 -->
```

If I then go to the address bar and press enter, it changes to:

```
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<result code="done" />
<!-- fe02.api.del.ac4.yahoo.net uncompressed/chunked Thu Aug  7 02:07:45 PDT 2008 -->
```

Any ideas how to get it to work directly from the bookmarks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you sniff the traffic to find what's actually being sent?  Is it sending any auth data at all and it's incorrect or being presented in a form the server doesn't like, or is it never being sent by firefox at all?

Answer (score 2):

@travis Looks very nice! I will sure take a look into it. I can think of several places I can use that

I never got round to sniff the traffic but found out that a php site on my own server with http-auth worked fine, so i figured it was something with delicious. I then created a php page that does a wget of the delicious api and everything works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Does calling the method twice work?

Seems to me that your authentication is being approved after the content arrives, so then a second attempt now works because you have the correct cookies.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend checking out the [iMacros addon for Firefox](http://www.iopus.com/imacros/firefox/). I use it to login to a local web server and after logging in, navigate directly to a certain page. The code I have looks like this, but it allows you to record your own macros:

```
VERSION BUILD=6000814 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://10.20.2.4/login
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:introduce ATTR=NAME:initials CONTENT=username-goes-here
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=NAME:introduce ATTR=NAME:password CONTENT=password-goes-here
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:introduce ATTR=NAME:Submit&&VALUE:Go
URL GOTO=http://10.20.2.4/timecard
```

I middle click on it and it opens a new tab and runs the macro taking me directly to the page I want, logged in with the account I specified.