# Create a Delicious Bookmarklet in Firefox using Delicious API

Tags: javascript, firefox, bookmarklet, delicious-api

I want to create a Delicious bookmarklet in Firefox that bookmarks the current page with a predefined tag.

For proof of concept, if I enter this url, it works:

```
https://john:pwd@api.del.icio.us/v1/posts/add?url=http://www.google.com&
    description=http://www.google.com&tags=testtag
```

But this as a bookmarklet doesn't, I get *access denied*:

```
javascript:(

    function()
    {
        location.href = 'https://john:pwd@api.del.icio.us/v1/posts/add?url=' 
            + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)
            + '&description=' + encodeURIComponent(document.title)   
            + '&tags=testtag';
    }

)()
```

Is this possible via a javascript bookmark?

**Update:** I tried this, but still got the *access denied* error, so it has something to do with Javascript/Firefox.

```
javascript:(

    function()
    {
        location.href = 'https://john:pwd@api.del.icio.us/v1/posts/add?url='
            + 'http://www.google.com'
            + '&description=' + 'http://www.google.com' + '&tags=testtag';
    }

)()
```

**Update 2:**
After trying many variations of the above and on different browsers, I still can't get past the *access denied message*, so offering a bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is Firefox trying to protect you from security issues when running Javascript.  When I tried typing in your example into my address bar, Firefox prompted me to ask if I am sure I want to log in to `api.del.icio.us`.

This other question concerning [HTTP auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544/http-auth-in-a-firefox-3-bookmarklet) looks similar to your question, maybe it will help you.

---

**Update:**

I used Firebug's *Net* panel and its Javascript console, and I was able to see the request/response headers.

Here is the request from the Javascript console, which FAILED:

```
GET /v1/posts/add?url=http://www.spoons.com/&description=forks&tags=knives HTTP/1.1
Host: api.del.icio.us
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708950/2740195
Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

And, here is the request from the address bar, which WORKED:

```
GET /v1/posts/add?url=http://www.spoons.com/&description=forks&tags=knives HTTP/1.1
Host: api.del.icio.us
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

The only difference seems to be the `Referer` header, which caused the *access denied* response.  The setting *network.http.sendRefererHeader* in Firefox's *about.config* can be set to 0 which turns off the `Referer` header.  When I tried this, then the Javascript console method started working.

There is a Firefox extension called [refspoof](http://refspoof.mozdev.org/faq.html) which is useful for sending your own custom `Referer` headers, maybe that can help here.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I've tried tracing via Firebug, but really couldn't get anywhere with that as https limits what you can see.  When I put the input the url directly, I get the prompt, click OK and it works.  When you put it in a bookmarklet, it acts differently.

Comment: That sounds promising.  I'll give it a try tonight.  If it works in the console, it should work for a bookmarklet.

Comment: Thanks!  It worked.  Not sure if I want to install refspoof, as I don't mind disabling the referrer setting via about:config for now.  Maybe I can make an extension that sets it to 0, runs a script and sets it back to 2.  Offhand, other than sites not getting credit for being a referrer, what are the consequences for keeping referrer to 0 permanently?  I also wonder why Delicious/Yahoo did it this way?

Comment: Nevermind, reading up on the referrer option - lots of consequences disabling it.

Comment: It is probably a security feature -- if I embed some script on my page that calls their API, I might be able to trick people into bookmarking my page.  The referer header may indicate this sort of trickery, so they reject it.

Comment: Yes, that's what someone in Delicious's api forum said to me.  Anyways, I would guess the api is subject to change and this might not work pending future changes, but I doubt the Yahoo folks are reading this.  Anyways, my motives are not pernicious, but to save myself time.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing `url=`.

Comment: I tried your example (with the URL encoded) in Firefox 3.6 and it worked. Are you logged into Delicious with another username? Are you using a Yahoo ID to log into Delicious?

Comment: It did? Awesome.  I'm using FF 3.6.2 and I completely exited FF and tried a non-Yahoo and Yahoo account.  Still won't work.  For the Yahoo account, I used zzz:pwd and zzz@yahoo:pwd.  Also turned off my firewall and didn't work.  Did you get a warning messagebox that read "You are about to log in to the site with ... but the website does not require authentication?

Comment: I tried a non-Yahoo account and it worked (it did show the authentication warning). According to http://delicious.com/help/api Yahoo accounts use a /v2 path and require OAuth.

Comment: Maybe you found a bug?  I posted this issue to the delicious forum and they said it shouldn't work.  http://support.delicious.com/forum/comments.php?DiscussionID=4334&page=1#Comment_18163.  Anyways, I tried OAuth, used v2 and got this: Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem="unable_to_determine_oauth_type", realm="yahooapis.com".